# Get Record Type Id by Developer Name

Tags: apex, record-type, developername

How to get record type Id in apex having its system DeveloperName (not a Name/Label).

UPD:

*There is a similar question here
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=What+would+be+the+best+approach+to+get+the+recordtype+id
but it is more general and the best answer selected may confuse searchers. This question is more specific and has a simple oneliner as a solution, which is more accurate with the current API.*

Answer (score 3):

For example you have RecordType on Account with name 'Person Account' and DeveloperName 'Person_Account'

```
acc.RecordTypeId = SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Person_Account').getRecordTypeId();
```

Comment: For the default Person Account Record Type it would be `.get('PersonAccount')`